# Estimate parameters of a quadratic function

Tags: functions, estimation

Suppose that we have two data points which tell us about the output of some function $f(x)$:

1. $(0, 50)$
2. $(10, 150)$

We know that the function is quadratic (so it's something like $ax^2 + bx + c$). The question is: how do we estimate the parameters $a, b$ and $c$ in such a way that the resulting function matches our data best?

Does this have to be regression, or is there some easier way?

Comment: Notice that your target function $(ax^2 + bx + c)$ has $3$ unknowns, and you have $2$ points of information. Even in a simple scenario, you will not be able to find a unique quadratic that passes through these points

Comment: You will need at least 3 data points to even start this in any meaningful way. With three non-collinear points there will be a unique quadratic which comes from solving 3 simultaneous equations for a, b c when you sub in the (x, y) values for the quadratic. For 4 or more data points you can find the optimal quadratic using a variation on regression.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assume $f(x) = a x^2 + b x + c$. The points give the equations
$$
50 = f(0) = c \\
150 = f(10) = 100 a + 10 b + c = 100 a+ 10 b + 50 \iff \\
10a + b = 10
$$
So your $c$ is determined, but $a$ and $b$ are not, you have to choose either $a$ or $b$.

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I decided to do. I set *b* to zero and lived happily ever after.